# My apartment used to be a hotel room

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I'm needing help with my exhaust fan in my bathroom. It is located on the same wall the door is. Let me give a little history about my apartment (technically a studio apartment) all of the studio apartments in my building on each side have 6 on top and 6 studios on the bottom. All of the studio apartments used to be motel rooms for at least 20+ years. Well I have a downstairs studio and my exhaust fan looks like it has been there since the bathroom was constructed for the motel, the fan is turning clock wise but I feel air when I put my hand up to the fan. Plus I will come home and you can see other tenants cigarette smoke in my studio. Please help me figure out what to do with the exhaust fan.

Comment: You've got "in the wall ducts"  that are commonly shared with other units.  Check to see if your vent has a damper that's stuck open. If you can vent out of a window, seal your problem vent.  Another alternative is to run your exhaust fan while you're out to keep out the smoke.

Comment: As @JACK states, you might want to keep it running to provide negative pressure, but might want to add a **motor** speed (phase) control to save on electricity. An ordinary light dimmer *might* burn out the motor!

Comment: Please take the [tour] - you'll find that this isn't a general discussion forum, but a Question & Answer board. You haven't asked us a question that we can help solve - What is it that you actually want to do? The history doesn't mean much except that there might be a shared duct somewhere. Do you own this apartment and can make modifications or are you a renter who cannot make changes to a property owned by someone else? Please [edit] your _question_ to ask an actual question that we can address.